# How to ignore the second letter from the user input

Tags: c++, char, getline

I have here a main menu that ask for the Choice of the user. The problem is whenever the user input Choice like 'AB' 'BC' it proceed to the other section since the program read the '(A)B' or the '(B)C. I want error to pop up if the user enter a choice like this
[image]

Comment: If you get more than one character you should report an error and ask to enter a valid option: A, B or C.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], we can't tell you what's wrong with code we can't see

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire line as a string, test its size, and report an error if it is more than 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Enter A, B or C\n";
  std::string line;
  std::getline(std::cin, line);
  if (line.size() > 1)
  {
    std::cerr << "Invalid input\n";
    return -1;
  }
  std::cout << "Your option is " << line << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

> Enter A, B or C
>
> ABBBBBBBBB
>
> Invalid input
>
> exit status 255